# Global variable not seen by user form sub

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have set a global dictionary object to keep track of file paths (keys being the "project name" which is the first word of the filename). The way this program works is a form opens in which the user can then open a file dialog to add files to a listbox. When this is done it should add the name and path to the dictionary.

Primary code:

```
Public project_dict As Scripting.Dictionary

Public Sub excelToPPT()
Set project_dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
...
Dim u As UserForm1
Set u = New UserForm1
u.Show
...
End Sub
```

UserForm code:

```
Private Sub cmdAddProject_Click()
    Dim project_fd As FileDialog
    Set project_fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    Dim it As Variant
    Dim path_split() As String
    Dim f_split() As String
    Dim f As String

    With project_fd
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .Title = "Select project excel file(s)"
        .Filters.Clear

        If .Show = -1 Then
            For Each it In .SelectedItems
                path_split = Split(it, "\")
                f_split = Split(path_split(UBound(path_split)))
                f = f_split(0)

                ' WHERE ERROR OCCURS
                project_dict.Add f, it

                Me.ListBox1.AddItem f
            Next it
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

When this is run the error is saying

```
project_dict.Add f, it
```

is no good because project_dict is not an object which I assume in this case is a scoping issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you just add a property for it on the UserForm and explicitly pass it instead of using a global?

Comment: You don't mention any error. Are we supposed to guess it.

Comment: Interesting. I set up the project (in PowerPoint 2016 PC), ran the main sub, clicked the button to open the file dialog, selected two Excel files, saw them appear in the ListBox and then clicked the X on the form to see the count of items in the dictionary output as 2 (I added a Debug.Print line). No errors anywhere!

Comment: @Comintern That looks like it might do the trick. I am relatively new to VBA and this is my first time using a UserForm

Comment: @JamieG That is strange! I wonder if perhaps I am missing a reference? I have the Microsoft Scripting Library checked so it can't be that...

Comment: The error message will tell you what is happening. It's utter madness to guess.

Comment: @Noodles I explained the issue fairly clearly in the question. I would ask you be constructive. Comintern was able to answer to answer the question successfully.

Comment: Error messages say SPECIFICLY what the problem is. There is no problem with your code. Your code WORKS. So the fact that other code also works isn't a solution. Error messages are usually quite specific.

Comment: @Noodles my code did not work. If it had then I would not be here :)

Comment: Your code does work. Therefore what is the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved by placing the below properties in the UserForm code and passing the dictionary in to the form instead of using a global variable.

```
Dim project_dict As Scripting.Dictionary

Public Property Get ProjectDictionary() As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set ProjectDictionary = project_dict
End Property

Public Property Let ProjectDictionary(ByVal pd As Scripting.Dictionary)
    Set project_dict = pd
End Property
```